# How does one batch/chunk both SQL source data and SQL destination data using Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm creating a quick-and-dirty ETL using Python from one database server (currently DB2) to another (MSSQL).  I'm just landing the data, so no transformation is occurring. The code I've written works, but it must retrieve the entire dataset first, and then insert the entire dataset to the destination.

I'd like to create a solution that would allow me to specify 'x' number of rows to pull from the source, and batch them to the destination.

I'm sure there's an elegant solution out there, but I'm not familiar enough with Python.  **I'm just looking for recommendations on an implementation, methods to use, or techniques.**

I'm using SQLAlchemy and pandas to accomplish the task.  My source and destination tables are identical (as much as possible, since datatypes differ between SQL implementations).  I'm populating a dataframe, then bulk inserting the data using MetaData and automap_base.

#### Bulk insert function

```
def bulkInsert(engine, df, tableName, schemaName = 'dbo'):
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(engine, only = [tableName], schema = schemaName)
    Base = automap_base(metadata = metadata)
    Base.prepare()
    tableToInsert = Base.classes[tableName]

    conn = engine.connect()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = conn)
    session = Session()
    session.bulk_insert_mappings(tableToInsert, df.to_dict(orient="records"), render_nulls = True)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    conn.close()
```

#### Grab the source data

```
db2 = db2Connect(db2Server)
df = pd.read_sql(query, db2, coerce_float=False)
db2.close()
```

#### Set up destination

```
engine = mssqlSAEngine(server, database)
```

#### Start bulk insert, replace NaN with NULL

```
bulkInsert(engine, df.where(pd.notnull(df), None), tableName)
```

I've had no trouble with successfully inserting data.  However, when I approach the million row mark, my system runs out of memory, and data starts paging.  Naturally, performance degrades substantially.

We do have other tools in house (SSIS for example), but I'm looking for a dynamic method.  In SSIS, I can either write a C# script task to basically accomplish what I'm doing here in Python, or create custom DFT's for each table.  With this method, I just need to pass the source and destination.

Comment: All major RDBMSs have bulk load/export utilities (although you may need specific permissions to use them).  This would mostly bypass the need for routing through SQLAlchemy/Pandas, or loading into program memory (because `df` contains your entire dataset).  Otherwise, you need either to write it out to a working file, or some form of query paging, where you filter rows in-flight based on some immutable data (insertion/update timestamp is popular, [just watch out for fenceposts](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)).

Comment: Thanks @Clockwork-Muse.  I have the ability to use the utilities, i.e. Import/Export wizard.  I was more looking to abstract the process to essentially a function that takes a source and destination, and performs the transfer.  I realize the code as written won't work, as you pointed out, the dataframe is in memory.  I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of methods for query paging/data streaming utilizing Python.

I'm able to do so using C#/.NET, with SqlBulkCopy, but it obviously requires compiled code.

Comment: ... no, these are [command-line utilities](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html), not wizards (which presumably are built on top of them).  So you could still use your python script, it just outputs to a CSV file, transfers that between servers, the runs the appropriate bulk-import command.  Once your result set gets above a certain size, this is vastly faster than what you're trying (because it can do things like temporarily disable constraint checking until all rows are inserted).